# On-site Landscape server blank page

Tags: software-installation, landscape

I've recently been tasked with finding some means of making sure all our Ubuntu servers are up to date more effectively than logging in to each and doing the apt update dance from the CLI. I found Canonical's Landscape system which looks ideal, and followed the manual installation instructions from https://docs.ubuntu.com/landscape/en/landscape-install-manual .

I've got quite a ways down the instructions, but when I browse to the new landscape server (the 'Set up first user' section), after filling in the details and clicking the submit button, I get an entirely blank page, with no URL either. How do I even begin fixing this?

Cheers!
James

Comment: This seem a lot like a browser issue. What browser are you using? Firefox and Chrome should work, but other browsers (especially IE) are not officially supported. Otherwise, you probably should look in /var/log/landscape-server for errors.

Comment: I’m using Vivaldi as the main browser (Chromium based) and Firefox as a backup - both give the same issue, and on different machines. I’ve tested through both on Linux and Mac. I can see the requests for the first page in the landscape application servers logs, but nothing after that.

Comment: A blank page and no logs makes me think the request is not going through to the server. Opening your browser's debugging console and checking network requests could reveal you a bit more (perhaps an incorrect address, SSL error, redirect loop, connection reset, etc.). Other than that, it could be anything from proxy to firewall.